# How to solve segmentation fault error on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am currently trying to use yolov8 to perform object detection on the raspberry pi 4. I have installed ultralytics and other necessary packages but whenever i run the code on the terminal it says "segmentation fault". Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
model.predict(source=0, show=True)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Segmentation fault means that some native code has tried to manipulate memory unavailable to it. Typically this is because of unhandled invalid input data. Are you _certain_ your code provides all the parameters needed and that they are as expected.  If you follow a tutorial it may be outdated.

Comment: Solve this is something yolov8 can do, NOT Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It is showinh me this error message:
"WARNING ⚠️ inference results will accumulate in RAM unless `stream=True` is passed, causing potential out-of-memory
errors for large sources or long-running streams and videos."
I have included the stream=True but i still keep getting the message

Comment: Might be useful if you posted the full text of the seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading torch and torchvision worked for me.

```
pip uninstall torch torchvision
pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 torchaudio==2.0.2
```

You can read more about this issue at https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/5274

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")

results = model.predict(source=0, stream=True)

for r in results:
    boxes = r.boxes  # Bounding box coordinates
    masks = r.masks  # Segmentation masks
    probs = r.probs  # Class probabilities
r.render()
```

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested and this is what i get:
    
1/1: 0... Success ✅ (inf frames of shape 640x480 at 30.00 FPS)
Segmentation fault

The segmentation fault error is still there and the video does not even show

Comment: I didn't suggest anything, I just formatted the code in Sam's answer.